# SQL Server 2008 XML input parameter to stored procedure to pass in "IN" clause values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

So I have a `checkboxlist` on an ASP.NET form.  I need the IDs of the selected `checkboxes` as part of an `IN` clause in a stored procedure (`SQL Server 2008`).  Quite straightforward really - let's say the user selects `1`, `2`, `4`, `7`, then my procedure would ask for values where `TranCode IN (1,2,4,7)`.  Since I can't do a dynamic `IN` statement, and I don't want to build the query dynamically, I thought XML would be a good choice.

I'm building the XML string thusly in VB.NET - `<chargecode><refnum>1</refnum><refnum>2</refnum></chargecode>`, etc.  `TranCode` and `RefNum` represent the same fields, they are just named differently between the transaction table and description table, so I can change `refnum` to something else in my XML if need be, but I'm definitely going to have to use `TranCode` for the comparison column.

In my stored procedure I've declared an XML variable called `@ChargeCodesXML`, which will contain the XML string passed in from VB.NET.  Basically all I need to do is pull all the refnum fields out of the XML file for comparison against `TranCode`.  The procedure has several joins, some aggregate functions, group bys, etc., but basically I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE TranCode IN (SELECT RefNum FROM MyXMLFile)
```

I've been searching around and have seen many complex XML queries, but nothing as simple as what I need, so I'm kind of overwhelmed by the examples I'm seeing.  Can someone please tell me how to modify my proc for this very simple comparison?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE TranCode IN (
                  SELECT T.N.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
                  FROM @ChargeCodesXML.nodes('/chargecode/refnum') AS T(N)
                  )
```

Comment: Great!  Worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should sort your problem:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE TranCode IN (
  SELECT
    ChargeCode.RefNum.value('.', 'INT')
  FROM
    @ChargeCodesXML.nodes('/chargecode/refnum') AS ChargeCode(RefNum)
)
```

The key part to this query is that you use the [nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method to shred the XML. If you're going to be spending any significant amount of time working with XML in SQL Server 2008, I suggest you do some reading up on this.